# How to change the size of a table?

Tags: resize, font-size

I have this table. I want to reduce size of table, but I can't change. `\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1pt}` doesn't work as I want.  What I should do???

```latex
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}||p{2cm}||p{2cm}||p{2cm}||p{2cm}||p{2cm}|}
        \hline
        Energy& \multicolumn{2}{|c|} {O16(p,np)O15}  & Energy & \multicolumn{2}{|c|} {O16(p,np)O15} \\
        \hline
        & Q & Cross section(mb) & & Q & Cross section(mb) \\
        \hline
        20 & 216 & 4,31E+00 & 60 & 2216 & 4,42E+01\\
    \end{tabular}

\caption{Number of reaction channels and cross section for O16(p,np)O15 on INCL model}

\label{incl_2}

\end{table}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are manually specifying the width of your columns by using `p{2cm}`. Instead, you can replace this specifier with something like `c`. This will make all of the text in your column centred, and the width of each column will be determined automatically. Then, if your table is still too wide, you can use something like `\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1pt}`.

```latex
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-5pt}
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabular}{|c||c||c||c||c||c|}
        \hline
        Energy& \multicolumn{2}{|c|} {O16(p,np)O15}  & Energy & \multicolumn{2}{|c|} {O16(p,np)O15} \\
        \hline
        & Q & Cross section(mb) & & Q & Cross section(mb) \\
        \hline
        20 & 216 & 4,31E+00 & 60 & 2216 & 4,42E+01\\
    \end{tabular}

\caption{Number of reaction channels and cross section for O16(p,np)O15 on INCL model}

\label{incl_2}

\end{table}
```